# How to disable initial pause in scrolling when holding up and down arrows in Chrome?

Tags: google-chrome, scrolling

I've been trying to find a way to get rid of that annoying scroll pause that chrome does while scrolling using the up and down arrow keys. It works when just tapping the keys, however I'd like for it to scroll fluid and consistently while holding them. I've tried various smooth scroll add ons but none of them seem to have the option I'm looking for.

Comment: Is it the same delay timing as the default keyboard delay setting? Like in a text editor/notepad try holding a key or arrow, is the delay the same? Tried changing that delay? Should be somewhere in Desktop/Windows settings. You probably won't be able to type normally if you set it to near zero delay, if that's even possible.

Comment: @Xen2050: Congratulations on receiving your sixth Custodian badge and the Thalia hat!

Comment: @Scott Cool, thanks! I forgot about the controls, enlarging the Thalia works & looks neat. Thought the Sufganiyot looked like a "cake" I could "eat," but didn't look so hot. If only I could get back the Pirate Hat & Parrot I had last year...

Comment: @Xen2050: Well, remember, there are usually as many "secret" hats as there are documented ones.  Maybe some cooler ones will start coming to light soon.

Comment: @Xen2050 Yes! This does exactly what I need! There is still a very slight delay, but it's hardly noticeable. Thank you :)

Comment: any answer for this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Is it the same delay timing as the default keyboard delay setting?

Like in a text editor/notepad try holding a key or arrow, is the delay the same?

Try changing that delay so it starts repeating faster. Should be a setting somewhere in Desktop/Windows settings, probably under keyboard, but it depends on what OS/Desktop you're running.

You probably won't be able to type normally if you set it too close to a zero delay  (if it will let you go that fast/low)

---

An extension might be even better, and wouldn't change the default keyboard settings. [SmoothScroll](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/smoothscroll/nbokbjkabcmbfdlbddjidfmibcpneigj?hl=en) or [Smooth Key Scroll](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/smooth-key-scroll/gphmhpfbknciemgfnfhjapilmcaecljh/reviews?hl=en) might be what you're looking for too, there are always new extension coming out so have a search.